# Multiple WARs trying to load classes of each other

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, war, ear

I have a Java EE application deployed on GlassFish. This application has 2 web modules inside it:

- 1st with some RESTful-services (business logic)
- 2nd with a JSF application (admin console)

When I deploy my application, all deploys ok, but I see many `ClassNotFound` warnings and exceptions in the log (from both of them, 1st war and 2nd war).

1st war:

```
SEVERE: Unable to load annotated class: com...web.admin.AdministrationBean
SEVERE: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com...web.admin.AdministrationBean
```

2nd war:

```
WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class com...web.rest.SomeResourse, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com...rest.SomeResourse
```

Everything works and all, but those log warnings and errors are really annoying.

Looks like there's something wrong in the application properties, but I checked them and all looks ok (when I try to deploy them separate from each other, all is ok).

Maybe I need some `application.xml` settings for separate loading in GlassFish? I Googled it, but didn't find useful information.

Comment: People votes down, but dont explain why... My question is useless or unclear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this is bug in GlassFish:

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16249